# Компилляция .NET Core приложения

Tags: c#, компиляция, .net-core

Как можно скомпиллировать .NET Core приложение для конечного пользователя?
То есть, чтобы не было отладочных файлов.

Что означают файлы {название проекта}.deps.json, {название проекта}.runtimeconfig.json и {название проекта}.runtimeconfig.dev.json?

Comment: Используйте меню Visual Studio - Build - Publish.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Ну Студия создаёт отладочные файлы, так не давайте их пользователю, давайте только нужные файлы, делов-то!

Comment: Ах эти двойные стандарты... То у нас подобное [не дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1221858/220553), где сообщество всеми силами не хотело голосовать за подобное, то сразу закрыли, да еще и модератор...